# COUNTIFS on multiple columns

Tags: excel, countif

I would like to return the count of the number of rows for which ANY of the columns have the number `1`. The table is three columns, and each column can contain either `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`. Example:

Col1 | Col 2 | Col 3
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 2 | 3
0 | 0 | 0
3 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2
etc.

I would like the formula to return `3`.

Comment: Use an extra column to store intermediate values, and countif on that. Complex formulas in Excel are difficult to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--((A1:A10=1)+(B1:B10=1)+(C1:C10=1)>0))
```

Change the 10s to however far down you need to go.